# Android Studio, CRUD no SQL Server 2008

Tags: android, sql-server

Estou fazendo uma aplicação na empresa onde eu poderei fazer cadastro de condôminos e visitantes do local. Estou fazendo uma conexão com o banco de dados SQL Server 2008 tranquilamente, mas não consigo fazer o CRUD na aplicação. Fiz o teste de **Adicionar** um condômino, mas quando aperto o botão "Salvar", o ProgressBar apenas fica rodando e nada acontece.

```
public class MegaPermanentes extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declarando as variáveis //
ConnectionClass connectionClass;
EditText editName, editDocument;
Button addButton, editButton, deleteButton;
ProgressBar progressBar;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mega_permanentes);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    editDocument = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDocumento);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            AddInfo addPro = new AddInfo();
            addPro.execute("");
            editName.setText("");
            editDocument.setText("");

        }
    });
}



public class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSucess = false;

    String infoName = editName.getText().toString();
    String infoDocu = editDocument.getText().toString();
    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(infoName.trim().equals("") || infoDocu.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Por favor digite um nome e um documento";
        else{
            try{
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null){
                    z = "Erro na conexão com o Banco de Dados";
                }
                else
                {
                    String query = "insert into usuarios (nome,endereco) values ('" + infoName + "','" +infoDocu + "')";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    z = "Cadastro inserido com sucesso";
                    isSucess = true;
                }
            }catch( Exception ex){
                isSucess = false;
                z = "Exceptions";
            }
        }

        return z;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection connectionclass (String user, String password, String database, String server)
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.169/ANDROID_SQL;instance=MEGACONTROL;user=sa;password=@dm1n102030";
        //ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip +"/"+ db +";""istance=MEGACONTROL""";user=" + un + ";password="+ password + ";";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error here 1", e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error here 2", e.getMessage());
    }

    return connection;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não está usando o AsyncTask corretamente.

1) Não tem um método `onPostExecute()` que recebe o valor de retorno do método `doInBackground()` para pelo menos fazer sumir a ProgressBar ou exibir algum erro. Por isso ela fica na tela rodando, pois você exibe ela no `onPreExecute()` e depois não faz mais nada com ela, então o processamento do banco de dados pode até ter acontecido, mas você não faz nada com os resultados. Poderia ser algo assim:

```
 // O sua classe deve estender AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
 // O valor z que você retorna no doInBackground() é entregue como o result abaixo
 @Override     
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 }
```

2) Você definiu o seu AsyncTask para ter Strings de entrada mas executa ele passando um valor vazio no `execute()` e depois recupera as Strings dos EditTexts dentro do `doInBackground`. Ficou estranho (e nem sei se isso funciona). O normal seria ter passado os dados de seus EditTexts como parâmetros de entrada no execute() e recuperar o valores na variável `params` do `doInBackGround()`:

Ex:

```
String infoName = editName.getText().toString();
String infoDocu = editDocument.getText().toString();
addPro.execute(infoName, infoDocu);
```

...

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... inputs) {
    if(inputs[0].trim().equals("") || inputs[1].trim().equals(""))
        z = "Por favor digite um nome e um documento";
  ...
}
```

Lembrando que sua classe deve estender de `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

3) A sua classe AddInfo tem variáveis globais inúteis:

- `z` (Por que não criou ela local no doInBackground)?
- `isSuccess` (Não serve prá nada)
- `infoName` e `infoDocu` (podem ser movidas para o listener do botão, como fiz no passo acima)

Vale a pena dar uma olhada nessa documentação: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Desculpe a demora pela resposta Márcio, fiz o que disse, mas não consigo declarar infoName e infoDocu no addPro.execute(). O problema do ProgressBar desapareceu, ela não fica mais rodando infinitamente, mas mesmo assim não há o Insert dos dados.

Comment: Você tentou debugar o app para ver se a execução chega até o comando de insert. Se chega, tem que ver como estão as variáveis infoName  e infoDocu nesse ponto, se estão com valores válidos. Se ainda assim não está inserindo, então é algum outro problema com essa classe PreparedStatement  que eu não conheço.

Comment: Qual outra classe que é utilizada para a inserção de dados em um banco? Perdoe toda a dificuldade, ainda estou no começo do ramo de Mobile (Android)

Comment: Sinceramente não sei. Até hoje só trabalhei com banco de dados SQLite local no aparelho.

Comment: Márcio, ele cai no if(con == null) e logo após ele já cai no exceptions com o erro: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". Sabe o que seria?

Comment: Márcio, já peguei. Era problema no connectionClass. Obrigado, de vdd.